# Can my crashing Macbook Pro (mid 2012) be saved?

Tags: macbook-pro, crash

I'm hoping someone can help me diagnose a problem with my mid-2012 Macbook Pro. It is crashing intermittently (aprox 3 or 4 times per month).

The most recent 2 crash reports are below and I'd greatly appreciate help figuring out whether they offer clues about the source of the problem. I'd hate to trash the computer if it can be fixed -- aside from the instability, the machine is powerful enough for my current needs.

I've tried resetting the SMC and NVRAM, swapping out the SSD, installing a new hard drive/SSD ribbon cable, removing the OWC Data Doubler that had replaced my optical drive, running Apple diagnostics, and checking the RAM with memtest. I've searched the web to no avail, and I don't have the expertise to make full use of the system logs.

The machine is a MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2012) with 16GB RAM and the NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M graphics card. The startup drive is a 120 GB Samsung 840 series SSD; previously I was using a 500 GB Samsung 850 series SSD. I'm running Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.6. There is currently nothing at all in the optical drive bay.

I thought there might have been an issue with Google Chrome and its use of GPU hardware acceleration, so I've switched to Firefox but the crashes have continued (*perhaps* less frequently). I believe Firefox was running (and Chrome was not running) during the crashes reported below. Thanks in advance for your help!

Crash 2 (mid February, 2019):

```
*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 6 caller 0xffffff800e58776f): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f8fcb3543, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x0000000000000000, CR3: 0x0000000446d1804b, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0xffffff81d3f2bdec, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0x0000000000000014, RDX: 0x0000000000000005
RSP: 0xffffff91fe383140, RBP: 0xffffff91fe383160, RSI: 0x0000000000000000, RDI: 0xffffff8031711000
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0x00000000000000c0, R10: 0x0000000000025d60, R11: 0x00000000000000f0
R12: 0xffffff80314ce780, R13: 0xffffff80316a9000, R14: 0xffffff8031711000, R15: 0x0000000000000005
RFL: 0x0000000000010282, RIP: 0xffffff7f8fcb3543, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x6, PL: 0, VF: 0

Backtrace (CPU 6), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff91fe382c10 : 0xffffff800e46c1c6 
0xffffff91fe382c60 : 0xffffff800e595274 
0xffffff91fe382ca0 : 0xffffff800e587544 
0xffffff91fe382d10 : 0xffffff800e41e1e0 
0xffffff91fe382d30 : 0xffffff800e46bc3c 
0xffffff91fe382e60 : 0xffffff800e46b9fc 
0xffffff91fe382ec0 : 0xffffff800e58776f 
0xffffff91fe383030 : 0xffffff800e41e1e0 
0xffffff91fe383050 : 0xffffff7f8fcb3543 
0xffffff91fe383160 : 0xffffff7f8fcb2781 
0xffffff91fe3831a0 : 0xffffff7f8fcb3525 
0xffffff91fe3831d0 : 0xffffff7f8fcb425d 
0xffffff91fe383200 : 0xffffff7f8f464f83 
0xffffff91fe383240 : 0xffffff7f8fcbcb72 
0xffffff91fe383260 : 0xffffff7f8fca2a82 
0xffffff91fe3833e0 : 0xffffff7f8fca6d21 
0xffffff91fe383430 : 0xffffff7f8fca50df 
0xffffff91fe3834b0 : 0xffffff7f8fca12ca 
0xffffff91fe383630 : 0xffffff7f8fca6d21 
0xffffff91fe383680 : 0xffffff7f8f479abd 
0xffffff91fe3836b0 : 0xffffff7f8fca6bfd 
0xffffff91fe3836f0 : 0xffffff7f8f479c4d 
0xffffff91fe383730 : 0xffffff7f8f47a388 
0xffffff91fe3839e0 : 0xffffff7f8fca7459 
0xffffff91fe383a10 : 0xffffff7f8f479304 
0xffffff91fe383a60 : 0xffffff7f8f47910f 
0xffffff91fe383ab0 : 0xffffff7f8f478302 
0xffffff91fe383af0 : 0xffffff800eac1978 
0xffffff91fe383b40 : 0xffffff7f8fca724a 
0xffffff91fe383b70 : 0xffffff800eaca567 
0xffffff91fe383cb0 : 0xffffff800e542bf4 
0xffffff91fe383dc0 : 0xffffff800e4716e0 
0xffffff91fe383e10 : 0xffffff800e44ea3d 
0xffffff91fe383e60 : 0xffffff800e46154b 
0xffffff91fe383ef0 : 0xffffff800e57171d 
0xffffff91fe383fa0 : 0xffffff800e41e9e6 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(378.26)[AE312652-F3AF-3BFD-AEFF-FE4CCCC33BA9]@0xffffff7f8f444000->0xffffff7f8f4dcfff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[4FAE8181-B0B4-3A30-B0F3-77F48D2486E5]@0xffffff7f8f414000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(211.15)[37BCC686-AF99-3381-AC4F-E54A347E0F40]@0xffffff7f8f429000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[AEA4C7F5-CCB0-338B-B471-CF28A9792522]@0xffffff7f8ec94000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(519.20)[0E507098-E375-39B7-9AE2-AFF2C7A5D961]@0xffffff7f8f004000
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics(10.3.6)[DC3B09B2-33BC-35C9-BB93-B3DE7B51DDA1]@0xffffff7f8fc98000->0xffffff7f8fd09fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(211.15)[37BCC686-AF99-3381-AC4F-E54A347E0F40]@0xffffff7f8f429000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[AEA4C7F5-CCB0-338B-B471-CF28A9792522]@0xffffff7f8ec94000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(519.20)[0E507098-E375-39B7-9AE2-AFF2C7A5D961]@0xffffff7f8f004000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(378.26)[AE312652-F3AF-3BFD-AEFF-FE4CCCC33BA9]@0xffffff7f8f444000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
17G65

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Thu Jun 21 22:53:14 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.71.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1AE5ACFD-3B6F-3D74-AD52-31F1430DBC6F
Kernel slide:     0x000000000e200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800e400000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800e300000
System model name: MacBookPro9,1 (Mac-4B7AC7E43945597E)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 11332715777776
last loaded kext at 11325305728143: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   254 (addr 0xffffff7f91da0000, size 12288)
last unloaded kext at 10558797666251: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc  5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f91d97000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   254
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   6.0.7f10
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.2.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.37
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    131
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   281.52
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.20.13
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   281.52
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.7f10
com.apple.driver.AGDCBacklightControl   3.20.13
com.apple.GeForce   10.3.2
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.3.6
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    211
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.20.13
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 254
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  254
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  353
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.50.6
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  748.51.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.6
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1240.19.1a3
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.9
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329.50.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 220.50.1
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   183
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   220.50.1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 680.2
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   680.15
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 281.52
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    526
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    10.3.2
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  10.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.20.13
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 281.52
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 281.52
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   519.20
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.20.13
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    378.26
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   211.15
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.20.13
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    519.20
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.7f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.7f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.7f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.7f10
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 262
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.7.8
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.40.2
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.60.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    439.70.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  140.70.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    680.15
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

EOF
Model: MacBookPro9,1, BootROM MBP91.00DA.B00, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.3 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.1f175
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x0000, 0x4D34373142314737334248302D434B302020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x859B, 0x435438473353313630424D2E433136465044
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.190.18.1a3)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.7f10, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 840 Series, 120.03 GB
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Crash 1 (early/mid February, 2019):

```
*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 6 caller 0xffffff802b78776f): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f2ceb34f4, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0xffffff7f2ceb34f4, CR3: 0x000000044554104b, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0x0000000000050301, RBX: 0xffffff804ec92000, RCX: 0x0000000000000014, RDX: 0x0000000000000005
RSP: 0xffffff924522b288, RBP: 0xffffff924522b2c0, RSI: 0xffffff924522b298, RDI: 0xffffff804ec92000
R8:  0x000000000000ffff, R9:  0x0000000000000001, R10: 0x0000000000050368, R11: 0x0000000000000170
R12: 0x0000000000000023, R13: 0xffffff804e8dac00, R14: 0xffffff924522b298, R15: 0x0000000000000012
RFL: 0x0000000000010282, RIP: 0xffffff7f2ceb34f4, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff7f2ceb34f4, Error code: 0x0000000000000010, Fault CPU: 0x6, PL: 0, VF: 1

Backtrace (CPU 6), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff924522ad50 : 0xffffff802b66c1c6 
0xffffff924522ada0 : 0xffffff802b795274 
0xffffff924522ade0 : 0xffffff802b787544 
0xffffff924522ae50 : 0xffffff802b61e1e0 
0xffffff924522ae70 : 0xffffff802b66bc3c 
0xffffff924522afa0 : 0xffffff802b66b9fc 
0xffffff924522b000 : 0xffffff802b78776f 
0xffffff924522b170 : 0xffffff802b61e1e0 
0xffffff924522b190 : 0xffffff7f2ceb34f4 
0xffffff924522b2c0 : 0xffffff7faceb3525 
0xffffff924522b2f0 : 0xffffff7faced21d0 
0xffffff924522b340 : 0xffffff7facede09f 
0xffffff924522b3d0 : 0xffffff7facedfb95 
0xffffff924522b430 : 0xffffff7facec0461 
0xffffff924522b5e0 : 0xffffff7fac65c728 
0xffffff924522b660 : 0xffffff7fac65c1c1 
0xffffff924522b680 : 0xffffff7fac65e630 
0xffffff924522b6c0 : 0xffffff7fac66698a 
0xffffff924522b6f0 : 0xffffff7fac679cfc 
0xffffff924522b730 : 0xffffff7fac67a139 
0xffffff924522b9e0 : 0xffffff7facea7459 
0xffffff924522ba10 : 0xffffff7fac679304 
0xffffff924522ba60 : 0xffffff7fac67910f 
0xffffff924522bab0 : 0xffffff7fac678302 
0xffffff924522baf0 : 0xffffff802bcc1978 
0xffffff924522bb40 : 0xffffff7facea724a 
0xffffff924522bb70 : 0xffffff802bcca567 
0xffffff924522bcb0 : 0xffffff802b742bf4 
0xffffff924522bdc0 : 0xffffff802b6716e0 
0xffffff924522be10 : 0xffffff802b64ea3d 
0xffffff924522be60 : 0xffffff802b66154b 
0xffffff924522bef0 : 0xffffff802b77171d 
0xffffff924522bfa0 : 0xffffff802b61e9e6 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(378.26)[AE312652-F3AF-3BFD-AEFF-FE4CCCC33BA9]@0xffffff7fac644000->0xffffff7fac6dcfff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[4FAE8181-B0B4-3A30-B0F3-77F48D2486E5]@0xffffff7fac614000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(211.15)[37BCC686-AF99-3381-AC4F-E54A347E0F40]@0xffffff7fac629000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[AEA4C7F5-CCB0-338B-B471-CF28A9792522]@0xffffff7fabe94000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(519.20)[0E507098-E375-39B7-9AE2-AFF2C7A5D961]@0xffffff7fac204000
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics(10.3.6)[DC3B09B2-33BC-35C9-BB93-B3DE7B51DDA1]@0xffffff7face98000->0xffffff7facf09fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(211.15)[37BCC686-AF99-3381-AC4F-E54A347E0F40]@0xffffff7fac629000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[AEA4C7F5-CCB0-338B-B471-CF28A9792522]@0xffffff7fabe94000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(519.20)[0E507098-E375-39B7-9AE2-AFF2C7A5D961]@0xffffff7fac204000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(378.26)[AE312652-F3AF-3BFD-AEFF-FE4CCCC33BA9]@0xffffff7fac644000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
17G65

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Thu Jun 21 22:53:14 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.71.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1AE5ACFD-3B6F-3D74-AD52-31F1430DBC6F
Kernel slide:     0x000000002b400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff802b600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff802b500000
System model name: MacBookPro9,1 (Mac-4B7AC7E43945597E)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 39601862575398
last loaded kext at 39588109202585: com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3 (addr 0xffffff7faef96000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 39453349287035: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc  5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7faef88000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  404.30.2
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.2.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.37
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    131
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   281.52
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.5
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.20.13
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   281.52
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AGDCBacklightControl   3.20.13
com.apple.GeForce   10.3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.7f10
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.5
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.20.13
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    211
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  254
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 254
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  353
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.50.6
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  748.51.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1240.19.1a3
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.6
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.9
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329.50.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 220.50.1
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   183
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   220.50.1
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 281.52
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    526
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 680.2
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   680.15
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    10.3.2
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  10.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   519.20
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.20.13
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 281.52
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 281.52
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.20.13
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    378.26
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   211.15
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.20.13
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    519.20
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.7f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.7f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.7f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.7f10
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 262
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.40.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.7.8
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.7.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.60.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    439.70.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  140.70.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    680.15
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

EOF
Model: MacBookPro9,1, BootROM MBP91.00DA.B00, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.3 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.1f175
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x0000, 0x4D34373142314737334248302D434B302020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x859B, 0x435438473353313630424D2E433136465044
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.190.18.1a3)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.7f10, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 840 Series, 120.03 GB
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: 
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Comment: What peripherals do you have connected ? (USB ports)

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you discovered anything you can do to deliberately bring on one of these crashes? I ask because if it's only crashing a few times per month it makes it difficult to diagnose. Also, this may seem like a strange question, but can you clarify what actually happens when your MBP crashes? Finally, what do you mainly use your MBP for? Are you doing anything that requires the NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M graphics card?

Comment: Thanks for the questions. Here's some more info:

* The only peripheral I generally have connected is a USB flash drive (formatted as APFS, encrypted).

* I have not been able to figure out how to recreate the crash.

* Generally I'm not doing anything super intensive. Usually I've got a text editor open, plus Firefox (with a relatively large number of tabs), plus Preview. Sometimes I'll use word processor or spreadsheet applications, and once in a while I'll do some light photo editing using Krita or similar.

Comment: Forgot to respond to the question about what happens when the crashes occur. In general, the crashes are sudden & result in the kernel panic screen shown in the 1st image [on this page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200553) .("Your computer restarted because of a problem...")

Answer (score 2):

...check the battery and the fan, I had an identical computer (ram, 2drives, mid-2012) and this was happening.

Turned out that one of the problems was that the battery kept cutting off power randomly. You can test is this is the problem by taking out the battery and running it on charger power. Just an interesting note, battery diagnostics tools said that my battery was fine, so...

The other problem was that the computer is overheating, which can be controlled with [macs fan control](https://www.crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control) (and cleaning out your fan)

Comment: Also, if it can't be saved I'll happily buy it from you, I fix laptops and could use the parts or figure out something for it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!
* The crashes generally occur when the computer is running on charger power (but with the battery installed). This battery is very old and far beyond the point of needing to be replaced, so I'm almost always plugged in.
* I've now installed an application to monitor fan status, temperature, etc. It's a good idea. However, I don't think the crashes are produced by intense activity or high temps. I'll keep an eye on the stats, though.
* Do you seen anything in the crash reports that might be a clue?

Comment: I don't know how to read them, I'll run them past someone who does

Comment: Why not buy a new one from Newegg? They are cheap and (usually) work

Comment: It looks like (from what I understand), WindowServer crashed. Maybe re-install your operating system?